# How to transfer a value from angular .ts file to javascript .js file

Tags: javascript, angular

I am displaying a venn diagram in angular2+ template UI. I do this by calling a javascript file by importing that file into the code of .ts. But the values are static, taken from the same javascript file directly. Like -

**venn-example.js**

```
 var sets = [ {sets: ['A'], size: 12},
             {sets: ['B'], size: 12},
             {sets: ['A','B'], size: 2}];

var chart = venn.VennDiagram();
d3.select("#venn").datum(sets).call(chart);
```

But , here i want the value of sets to be coming from the angular.ts file.

**app.component.ts**

```
const url = '../../../../assets/venn.example.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-node-venn',
  templateUrl: './node-venn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./node-venn.component.scss']
})


export class NodeVennComponent implements OnInit {

  loadAPI: Promise<any>;
  sets

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {


  }


 //code to load Javascript.

  public buttonClicked() {
    this.loadAPI = new Promise((resolve) => {
        console.log('resolving promise...');
        this.loadScript();
    });
  }

  public loadScript() {
    console.log('preparing to load...')
    let node = document.createElement('script');
    node.src = url;
    node.type = 'text/javascript';
    node.async = true;
    node.charset = 'utf-8';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node);
  }


  seekAPI() {


    console.log("INSIDE  seekAPI() ")


            this.allAPI = [{ sets: ['channel'], size: 12 },
{ sets: ['incidentCity'], size: 12 },
{ sets: ['channel', 'incidentCity'], size: 2 }];

       }             
        }

      }
```

I want the value, sets from javascript venn.js file to be assigned the value of this.allAPI from app.ts file

i.e.

```
 var sets = this.allAPI;
```

Please help. How to relate / transfer such a value.

Comment: try localstorage

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables.

On ts set:

```
 window["allAPI"] = this.allAPI
```

On js use:

```
 var sets = window["allAPI"];
```

Not the cleanest approach.But quick.